# Reusing column name as declared variable in SQL select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, reusability

I am working on one project in which column names get changed in every month. So I am trying to declare a variable which contains the column names which I can reuse.
So I did this.

```
declare @cal_name varchar(max) = 'ID'
select @cal_name from Table_A
union all
select @cal_name from Table_B
```

But this just print the ID as a string in result box.
I don't want to use another variable to store sql statement, can anyone help me to make query as per my requirement.

Comment: It does not work that way.  You would have to use dynamic SQL.  Search on dynamic SQL.  And you state the server as language can vary.

Comment: but if I dont give column in single quotes while declaring it, then it will gives error

Comment: @Ben that is not OP's intent. Their intent is to have it write out and execute `SELECT ID FROM TABLE_A...` (notice the lack of quotes). This will require, OP, that you write your SQL statement into a VARCHAR variable, then execute it dynamically. That depends on what RDBMS you are using here.

Comment: You didn't describe what's behind that, from my point of view, really strange requirement - why on Earth do you change column names *every month*?!? Sounds like a nightmare; I'm trying to imagine several forms, reports, packages that rely on tables whose column names frequently change. I really wouldn't want to do your job. Just a thought/question: is that data model correctly set? How do those column names change? From ID_JANUARY to ID_FEBRUARY etc? If that's so, why don't you have two columns instead: ID and DATE, which actually *scales*, as opposed to your current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
declare @cal_name varchar(max) = 'ID'    
exec
(
    'select ' + @cal_name + ' from Table_A
    union all
    select ' + @cal_name + ' from Table_B'
)
```